# Using a Spark ML predict model without cluster

Tags: apache-spark, predict

Is it possible to query a machine learning "predicton model" built without a cluster setup (or a single node cluster)? I'm trying to query the model in the same JVM as a real time system I have.

Comment: Without a single node, how do you run Spark?

Comment: @cricket_007, Once the prediction model is generated, what purpose would Spark have? I'm not a data scientist so I may be misunderstanding. Once you have a model generated, can't you treat it conceptually as a function? Pass parameters in, receive output? Why would a cluster be necessary for that?

Comment: Your question was initially unclear. It sounded like you said the model was built without a cluster, to which I said, how would you build a model without one... To answer your secondary question, that depends how the data is stored. It should be noted that Spark has lazy execution, so if you are invoking a Spark function over some RDD, for example, then you will still need the cluster